# setInterval how does it work?

Tags: javascript, html

i want that at first Cell E is blinking red blue red blue...
and then Cell H is blinking red blue red......

But only Cell H is blinking.

What is to change?

it seems that it only run for i = selectCell=2

```
<script>

var blinkColors=new    Array('red','blue','red','blue','red','blue','red','blue');

var selectCell = 2;
 for (var i = 0; i <=selectCell -1; i++)

 {
        var blinkColor=0;

        var myBlink=setInterval(function(){doBlink(j);},300);

          function doBlink(x)
            {
             var jj=x;
             var blinkCell=document.getElementById('blinker'+jj);
             blinkCell.style.backgroundColor=blinkColors[blinkColor];
             blinkColor++;

             if(blinkColor==blinkColors.length)
                 {
                  stopBlink();
                 }

            }

          function stopBlink()
                {
                 clearInterval(myBlink);
                }
    }

</script>
</head>
```

Comment: [Like this](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/WindowOrWorkerGlobalScope/setInterval)

Comment: i mean cell blinker0 and blinker1 instead of cell E and cell H

Comment: Do post your HTML ?

Comment: Maybe you should adjust the title to better fit to the question?

Answer (score 0):

Here is an updated example.

```js
var blinkColors = new Array('red', 'blue', 'red', 'blue', 'red', 'blue', 'red', 'blue');

var selectCell = 2;
var blinkColor = 0;
var iterator = 0;

var myBlink = setInterval(function() {
  doBlink();
}, 300);

function doBlink() {
  var blinkCell = document.getElementById('blinker' + iterator);
  blinkCell.style.backgroundColor = blinkColors[blinkColor];
  blinkColor++;

  if (blinkColor == blinkColors.length) {
    blinkColor = 0;
    blinkCell.style.backgroundColor = "transparent";
    iterator++;

    if (iterator == selectCell)
      clearInterval(myBlink);
    else
      doBlink(iterator);
  }

}
```

```html
<div id="blinker0">Cell 1</div>
<div id="blinker1">Cell 2</div>
```

Comment: Thank you. It works as i want.Can you tell me why  do you call the function doBlink in the function doBlink?i

Comment: @Joachim - Only then blink will shift to next cell.

Answer (score 0):

I am creating a dynamic table using javascript Array. 
In the array, `zw` are the indices of the cells which should blink.
I have tried a lot but only the first cell is blinking.
Here is my code

```
var blinkColors = new Array('red', 'white','red', 'white','red', 'white' );
     var zw= new Array(1,4,5,9);
     var blinkColor = 0;
     var iterator = 0;

      var myBlink = setInterval(function() {
        doBlink();
      }, 300);

    function doBlink() {

       var blinkCell=document.getElementsByTagName('td');
       blinkCell[zw[iterator]].style.backgroundColor=blinkColors[blinkColor];

      if (blinkColor == blinkColors.length)

      {
        blinkColor = 0;
        blinkCell.style.backgroundColor = "transparent";
        iterator++;

        if (iterator == zw.lenght)
          clearInterval(myBlink);
        else
          doBlink(zw[iterator]);
       }
    }
 }
```

Comment: If you have a new question, please ask it by clicking the [Ask Question](/questions/ask) button. Include a link to this question if it helps provide context. - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/18595978)